# VLC for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, ppa, vlc

On VLC website, it says that it is supported for only release 16.04 and 18.04.

[image]

But when I run `sudo apt install vlc` directly in the terminal, it did install vlc. So, how did it work on 20.04?

I also tried to add their PPA (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily`), but it showed release file error, which also confirms that they have not released  it for 20.04.

So, how does it work with `sudo apt install vlc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vlc

You'll note the maintainers are Ubuntu [MOTU Developers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU)

The `vlc` found in Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) was packaged by Ubuntu *Master of the Universe* packagers, not the VLC project.

Comment: In case any readers don't understand the 'universe' term (sounds very *scifi* to me & I love it!), it's referring to the **Universe** repository (*Community maintained*) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu